# extract the values in a select query as Individual column based on space occurrence and pattern from SQLite database

Tags: sql, regex, sqlite

I have a SQLite table with data in its column "Description" like the following

```
 Description 
"DX SVFO FERX DETYUY09"
"FCS DFT DEUU WALK LIM"
"D FX DS"
```

Now i have to split them based on occurrence of space and remove space

**Expected result**

```
Description_1 Description_2 DESCRIPTION3
DX             SVFO          D
FCS            DFT           F
D              FX            D
```

Exact pattern expected is below. the description_1 takes any no of character in starting and so does the second , third one would take exactly a single character from the second space occurence to the third

Can you tell me how to build the pattern here to achieve this with a select statement in SQLITE Database

Br,
G

Comment: What is *null occurence*?

Comment: empty space after each word ."DX SVFO FERX DETYUY09" after DX there is an empty occurrence . that is the marker(end and start)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with string functions like `substr()` and `instr()` but it gets really complicated to access even the 2nd part, so I would do it with a recursive `CTE` which is also scalable:

```
with cte as (
  select descr, 1 idx, 
         substr(descr, 1, instr(descr, ' ') - 1) leftpart,
         substr(descr, instr(descr, ' ') + 1) rightpart
  from (select description || ' ' descr from tablename)
  union all
  select descr, idx + 1, 
         substr(rightpart, 1, instr(rightpart, ' ') - 1),
         substr(rightpart, instr(rightpart, ' ') + 1)
  from cte
  where idx < 3 
)
select 
  max(case when idx = 1 then leftpart end) Description_1,
  max(case when idx = 2 then leftpart end) Description_2,
  max(case when idx = 3 then substr(leftpart, 1, 1) end) Description_3
from cte
group by descr
order by descr, idx
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tjcQkDYcCr92gEVjEhE63Q/1).
Results:

```
| Description_1 | Description_2 | Description_3 |
| ------------- | ------------- | ------------- |
| D             | FX            | D             |
| DX            | SVFO          | F             |
| FCS           | DFT           | D             |
```